# How can I hide ALL series with the same ID with a button on highcharts? (line graph)

Tags: jquery, highcharts, linegraph

I have a simple highcharts line graph and I want to be able to hide (not remove) ALL series with the same id, with the click of a button.

I was thinking on checking for the id as a condition if (series.id === "rec") but for some reason I can't access the series id the same way I can access their names. I tried using:

```
$.each(chart.series, function (i, serie){
        chart.get('rec').hide()
});
```

But it just hides the first series with that id. Is this even possible? thanks!

here is my fiddle with more details: https://jsfiddle.net/grisfrancis/tua3td75/1/

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATED**

You need to use `serie.options.id` instead of `serie.id`

Because `id` property is inside of `options` field if you inspect the chart object.

Here is the solution [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tua3td75/5/).

Comment: You did not get the point... the problem isn't to hide the series, but to select all series with a specific ID and hide them all. In your example, you simply hide ALL series, not only the chosen ones.

Comment: Ohh my bad. Updated my answer with the solution.

Comment: nice! this is a fine solution

Comment: omg!! thank you Emre Bolat! it works perfectly.. I don't have the rep to oneup your answer but as soon as I hae 2 more points I will!